# Get an error cannot destructure property as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I try to get data from the backend and view that data in the frontend. To do this I tried this code.

```
function PostsLocation() {

    const { offerId } = useParams();
    console.log(offerId);

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});
    const [offerPosts, setOfferPosts] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=>{
        getOnePost();
    }, []);

    const getOnePost = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOneSellerOffer/${offerId}`)
            console.log(response);
            const allPost=response.data.oneOffer;
            setPosts(allPost);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
        }
    }
    console.log(posts);

    const PostId2=posts.postId
    console.log(PostId2);
    const type=typeof (PostId2);
    console.log(type);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getOneOfferPost();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (offerPosts && offerPosts.location) {
            console.log(offerPosts.location);
            console.log(offerPosts.location.longitude);
            console.log(offerPosts.location.latitude);
        }
    }, [offerPosts]);

    const getOneOfferPost = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${PostId2}`)
            console.log(response);
            const allOfferPost=response.data.onePost;
            setOfferPosts(allOfferPost);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
        }
    }
    console.log(offerPosts);

    const long = offerPosts?.location?.longitude;
    console.log(long);
    const lat=offerPosts?.location?.latitude;
    console.log(lat);

    const location={lat,long};
}
```

In this code, I called the first API and get data successfully. This image shows the data I got from this `console.log(posts)` code.

[image: Data get from first API]

Then I try to get this `posts.postId` ID to this variable `const PostId2`, I get this ID successfully. This image shows the ID that I got.

[image: ID image]

Then I try to pass this `PostId2` ID to the second API, but API call does not work. Then I try to restructure the ID `const {PostId2}=posts.postId` like this. Then I try again to call the second API but I got an error that says 'TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'PostId2' of 'posts.postId' as it is undefined'. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PostId2` variable is being populated as a result of the API call which happens in the first useEffect. Since the API call is async and the data isn't available on the initial render, the call to `getOneOfferPost` in useEffect doesn't get the updated id.

Also destructuring fails because the value isn't available initially.

To solve this, add PostId2 as dependency to `useEffect` which calls `getOneOfferPost` and add a conditional check before the API call

```
const getOneOfferPost = async () => {
  if(PostId2 !== undefined) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${PostId2}`)
        console.log(response);
        const allOfferPost=response.data.onePost;
        setOfferPosts(allOfferPost);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
    }
  }
}
const PostId2=posts.postId

useEffect(()=>{
    getOneOfferPost();
}, [PostId2]);
```

Comment: this works for me and I understand what the error was, appreciate your help.